# Is there a way to see CiviMail logs through the interface (v. 4.6.36.)

Tags: civimail

I am trying to troubleshoot some failed deliveries of emails in CiviMail. I would like to see the error logs. According to the documentation, they are stored in the local file system (well, obviously), but I do not have access to that. I am unable to find a view in the interface, where I could see the logs. Is it possible through the admin panels?

We use version 4.6.36.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you look under Administer - System Settings - Extensions and click on the Add New tab you'll see one called CiviCRM Log Viewer. Install that and then admins will be able to view the logs using the user interface.

Since you're on an old version of Civi you may need to download an older version of the extension from https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer, but if you don't have access to the file system then I'm not sure how you'd install it. Tricky.

Comment: I was imagining he was after the mail logs